# Drawing Non-Continuous Horizon Charts (d3)

Tags: d3.js

(apologies for my lack of knowledge upfront)

Horizon Charts seem to be handled differently than area charts in D3. I've seen previous answers on non-continuous data in area charts, using line.defined.  However, I'm not seeing how to accomplish that same effect in a horizon chart.

End goal: Where data is missing, skip or otherwise mask later, that point. As in this line.defined example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090), it shouldn't affect the curve of the path.

Ideally, the data in the json would just be a missing value, but I can add a type signifier if needed.

Is there a better approach - like adding a filled rectangle after the path was created in those spots to mask it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Wouldn't you just add several such (interrupted) lines for a horizon chart?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff D3 already has an efficient plugin for horizon charts, horizon.js (example here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1483226 )
I was attempting to use that rather than create my own from scratch, but I'm not seeing that they use line at all, so I can't use line.defined

Comment: Yes, that one is using areas. Might be easier to roll your own than trying to modify that one.

Comment: Wouldn't a bar chart be more appropriate here?

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the [d3.horizon plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/horizon) to support setting [area.defined](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#area_defined) for the area instance used internally.

For example, you can say:

```
var horizon = d3.horizon()
    .width(…)
    .height(…)
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d[1]); });
```